# Matlab Random Distribution Generation without overlapping

Tags: matlab, simulation, ansys

I need to generate fibers in a certain size of box or beam. The distribution will be random and without overlapping. The algorithm is shown in the image below along with the result.

[image: algorithm]
[image: result]

I am able to generate random distribution in Matlab but I can't figure out how to avoid overlapping as shown in the algorithm. The resultant I will be using in the Ansys simulation software for analysis.

The algorithm I have taken from other reference but I have modified parameters which are as under, fiber length 12mm, fiber diameter 35um, box size (40mm x 40mm x 160mm), fiber volume fraction = 2%,  and the number of fibers within the box is around 443500.

The said codings are beyond my expertise, can anyone help me write the code for the said algorithm in Matlab?

Comment: Ask the original authors for the generation code.  They should provide it.  I'd also ask your academic supervisor for advice, as they may be better positioned for this issue.  The exact code will be rather long and probably beyond the scope of what anyone can do here for free.  

If you can't do that, perhaps break down the question and ask for how to best model intersecting volumes in a 3D space?

Answer (score 0):

I used the attached algorithm for fiber insertion without overlap, it works

[image: Fiber generation]